# NODE: How to make swagger show route + endpoint on documentation

Tags: node.js, swagger, documentation

I'm documenting an existing node API. For this task, i'm using swagger-ui-express && swagger-autogen.

All routes are inside routes.js like this:

```
router.use('/my_route', require('./my_routes.js'));
```

And inside `my_routes.js`, I have a lot of endpoints, like this:

```
router.get('/', custom1.customFunction1);
router.get('/:custom2/:custom3', custom1.customFunction23);
router.put('/custom4', custom4.customFunction4);
```

The problem is that in `/documentation` page, all my endpoints are showing like this:
[swagger endpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbN4B.png)

How can I make swagger shows like this:
[swagger endpoints that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFPVF.png)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to configure your swagger.js file passing just the routes.js file, such as:

```js
const swaggerAutogen = require('swagger-autogen')();


const outputFile = './swagger-output.json';
const endpointsFiles = ['./routes.js'];

swaggerAutogen(outputFile, endpointsFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send this prefix in the options:

```
swaggerAutogen(outputFile, endpointsFiles, { basePath: '/my_route' });
```